# (wx)Maxima plot point by point, numbered

Tags: plot, maxima

I have a list of roots and I want to plot the real/imaginary parts. If `s=allroots()`, `r=realpart()` and `i=imagpart()`, all with `makelist()`. Since `length(s)` can get ...lengthy, is there a way to plot point by point and have them numbered? Actually, the numbering part is what concerns me most. I can simply use `points(r,i)` and get the job done, but I'd like to know their occurence before and after some sorting algorithms. It's not always necessary to plot *all* the points, I can plot up until *some* number, but I do have to be able to see their order of having been sorted out.

I have tried multiplot_mode but it doesn't work:

```
multiplot_mode(wxt)$
for i:1 thru length(s) do draw2d(points([r[i]],[i[i]]))$
multiplot_mode(none)$
```

All I get is a single point. Now, if this should work, using `draw2d`'s `label(["label",posx,posy])` is very handy, but can I somehow evaluate `i` in the `for` loop inside the `""`?

Or, is there any other way to do it? With Octave? or Scilab? I'm on Linux, btw.

---

Just to be clear, here's what I currently do: (I can't post images, here's the link: i.stack.imgur.com/hNYZF.png )

...and here is the wxMaxima code:

```
ptest:sortd(pp2); length(ptest);
draw2d(proportional_axes=xy,xrange=[sort(realpart(s))[1]-0.1,sort(realpart(s))[length(s)]+0.1],
 yrange=[sort(imagpart(s))[1]-0.1,sort(imagpart(s))[length(s)]+0.1],point_type=0,
 label(["1",realpart(ptest[1]),imagpart(ptest[1])]),points([realpart(ptest[1])],[imagpart(ptest[1])]),
 label(["2",realpart(ptest[2]),imagpart(ptest[2])]),points([realpart(ptest[2])],[imagpart(ptest[2])]),
 label(["3",realpart(ptest[3]),imagpart(ptest[3])]),points([realpart(ptest[3])],[imagpart(ptest[3])]),
 label(["4",realpart(ptest[4]),imagpart(ptest[4])]),points([realpart(ptest[4])],[imagpart(ptest[4])]),
 label(["5",realpart(ptest[5]),imagpart(ptest[5])]),points([realpart(ptest[5])],[imagpart(ptest[5])]),
 label(["6",realpart(ptest[6]),imagpart(ptest[6])]),points([realpart(ptest[6])],[imagpart(ptest[6])]),
 label(["7",realpart(ptest[7]),imagpart(ptest[7])]),points([realpart(ptest[7])],[imagpart(ptest[7])]),
 label(["8",realpart(ptest[8]),imagpart(ptest[8])]),points([realpart(ptest[8])],[imagpart(ptest[8])]),
 label(["9",realpart(ptest[9]),imagpart(ptest[9])]),points([realpart(ptest[9])],[imagpart(ptest[9])]),
 label(["10",realpart(ptest[10]),imagpart(ptest[10])]),points([realpart(ptest[10])],[imagpart(ptest[10])]),
 label(["11",realpart(ptest[11]),imagpart(ptest[11])]),points([realpart(ptest[11])],[imagpart(ptest[11])]),
 label(["12",realpart(ptest[12]),imagpart(ptest[12])]),points([realpart(ptest[12])],[imagpart(ptest[12])]),/*
 label(["13",realpart(ptest[13]),imagpart(ptest[13])]),points([realpart(ptest[13])],[imagpart(ptest[13])]),
 label(["14",realpart(ptest[14]),imagpart(ptest[14])]),points([realpart(ptest[14])],[imagpart(ptest[14])]),*/
 color=red,point_type=circle,point_size=3,points_joined=false,points(realpart(pp2),imagpart(pp2)),points_joined=false,
 color=black,key="",line_type=dots,nticks=50,polar(1,t,0,2*%pi) )$
```

This is for 14 zeroes, only. For higher orders it would be very painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that the problem is that you want to automatically construct all the `points([realpart(...), imagpart(...)])`. My advice is to construct the list of `points` expressions via `makelist`, then `append` that list to any other plotting arguments, then `apply` the plotting function to the appended list. Something like:

```
my_labels_and_points :
    apply (append, 
           makelist ([label ([sconcat (i), realpart (ptest[i]), imagpart (ptest[i])]),
                      points ([realpart (ptest[i])], [imagpart (ptest[i])])],
                     i, 1, length (ptest)));
all_plot_args : append ([proptional_axes=..., ...], my_labels_and_points, [color=..., key=..., ...]);
apply (draw2d, all_plot_args);
```

The general idea is to build up the list of plotting arguments and then apply the plotting function to that.

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll give it a try but only tomorrow, when I'll return with updates.

Comment: This works! I made it into a function, here's the code (probably childish): <pre>func(u,n):=block(,
 pnts:apply(append, makelist([ label([sconcat(i),realpart(u[i]),imagpart(u[i])]),
  points([realpart(u[i])],[imagpart(u[i])]) ],i,1,n) ),
 args:append([proportional_axes=xy,xrange=[sort(realpart(s))[1]-0.1,sort(realpart(s))[length(s)]+0.1],
 yrange=[sort(imagpart(s))[1]-0.1,sort(imagpart(s))[length(s)]+0.1],point_type=0],pnts),
return(apply(draw2d,args)))$</pre> and here's the pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/njV0Y.png Thank you, I can't vote up but I'll mark it as the chosen one. :-)

Comment: 'pre' doesn't seem to work. Anyway, this is the test for the picture: func(makelist(rhs(allroots(float(sum(x^k,k,0,100)))[k]),k,1,100),40) . It does need a few seconds to think, but it works!